# My Windows 10 pc is stuck in a boot loop

Tags: windows, boot, windows-10

I was trying to connect to someone's server. While I was working on that, my internet stopped working on my PC (it does work on other computers). I tried using System Restore to back the system up to a state from 4 days ago. System Restore performs several reboots during the restore, which is fine. But one of them led to a boot loop -- on restart, it says "Your PC will automatically restart in one minute. Windows ran into a problem and needs to restart. You should close this message now and save your work."

At this point, I can click on things on the desktop and can even open documents. But the Windows Key and the Taskbar never do anything.  The taskbar always gives me the "busy" cursor.

It duly restarts, and I get the same message again.

So as far as I know, System Restore did not complete.

Comment: Do you have a disc to possibly repair the system?

Comment: No, but a pro likely would. I can't tell it to not restart, even thought it wants to? The restart is so quick I can't do anything

Comment: Have you tried to boot in [safe mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode)?